C++: construct a std::string from a zero-length C-string
Does this code result in undefined behaviour?
const char *aptr = "";
std::string s(aptr, strlen(aptr));

Note (4) at cppreference appears to indicate it isn't, because [aptr, aptr) is not, I think, a valid range, but I'd appreciate confirmation.

It is not undefined. [aptr, aptr) is valid, it simply point to the null character in the empty string, and you will get an empty std::string

This is perfectly fine, why you have doubts if this is correct?

Also, you don't need the strlen. std::string can be constructed from a 0-terminated string.

That range is as valid as any other empty range.

Ok, thanks everybody. My confusion is that mathematically, the interval [n, n) means the numbers which are greater than or equal to n, and less than n, so it's an empty interval. This implies that [aptr,aptr) is not a valid range, unless C++ has its own definition of range (does it?)

@QF0 -- "empty interval" does not imply "not a valid range". A range can be empty.

@QF0 You can look at it this way, [n, n) can be translated to the loop for (int i = n; i != n; n++).  That is a valid loop and will never run since it reaches the end condition before the first iteration starts.

Maybe in your math an empty interval is not valid, but in mine it is.

[aptr, aptr) is a valid range. It is empty. You are constructing an empty string. Other ways to do that are:
std::string s1;
std::string s2(s1.c_str(),0);

On the other hand this is undefined:
std::string s3(s1.c_str(),42);  // noooo

Because [s1.c_str(),s1.c_str()+42) is not a valid range.


My confusion is that mathematically, the interval [n, n) means the numbers which are greater than or equal to n, and less than n, so it's an empty interval. This implies that [aptr,aptr) is not a valid range, unless C++ has its own definition of range (does it?)

The whole reason for using half-open ranges ubiquitously in the standard library is that they correctly represent empty ranges with no awkward corner cases.
Even though we're talking about ranges of iterators rather than intervals on a number line (as your example), intervals actually work the same way. Per wikipedia

Each interval (a, a), [a, a), and (a, a] represents the empty set, ...

Equivalently, it's perfectly fine to construct an empty std::string with one of
std::string s{charptr, 0};       // zero character count
std::string t{charptr, charptr}; // empty range [charptr, charptr)

